# How can I share media from ubuntu 13.04 to windows XP

Tags: 13.04, permissions, samba, shared-folders, media

So I have set up samba successfully and I am using it for file shares but when trying to do media shares I am having issues. Specifically the problem is that I can see the Media folder in Windows but then I can't go into them. I get permission denied. I have changed the /media/username to soft link to a /media/share folder and this is working. The problem is that the file system won't let me change permissions on a media sub directory even as root. As a result, I am trying to see if anyone else is sharing their media from a linux machine to a windows machine.  See below my attempt to change the directory perms.  My Passport is a WD external hard drive. I can see the My Passport folder in Windows I just can't open it.

soft link:

```
root@BigJackFly:/media# ls -ltr
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root       5 Sep 25 18:41 bjackfly -> share
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Sep 25 20:48 share


root@BigJackFly:/media/share# chmod 777 My\ Passport/
root@BigJackFly:/media/share# ls -ltr

drwx------ 1 bjackfly bjackfly 4096 Sep 25 21:04 My Passport

smb.conf
[mediashare]
   comment = Public Stuff
   path = /media/share
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
```

Comment: Does anyone have any advice? I am sure I am not the first to do this. Is there a better place I should post this question where someone might know??

Comment: What filesystem is the external harddrive formatted with? Some filesystem do not support unix permissions

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and solved it by adding the user to the samba share, with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <USERNAME>
```

just change < USERNAME > by the username (an ubuntu prevously added user) you want to access to the shared resource.

Also I didn't change any file, I just right click the folder from nautilus and use "Sharing options" menu.

Hope this help you